# What infos can I get from an adjacency matrix of a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I have this matrix for the multigraph G

\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
        1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\\end{matrix}

I have to find

- a partition in cycles (if it exists) for the set E (edges)
- an eulerian path (if it exists)
- a tree that generates G where $v_1, v_4, v_5, v_7, v_8$ are leaves
- six different subgraphs that are trees whose vertices are $v_4, v_5, v_6, v_8$

I find this exercise difficult. I would appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: Hint: draw the graph.

Comment: In past finals there where problems where it was asked to draw the graph. Not in this one tough.

Comment: If you're working by hand, it will be easier to draw the graph, even though you weren't asked to do so. Directly using an adjacency matrix is better on a computer.